# CMS Open Payments: How do use contains operator in JSON request URL for multiple records?

Tags: c#, json, post, ssis, get

I'm looking to use a contains operator in my JSON request URL. Here's the URL:

[https://openpaymentsdata.cms.gov/api/1/datastore/query/50fae62c-ced9-5e10-ad26-1cbc3381ac6b?keys=true&limit=5&offset=0&conditions[0][property]=covered_recipient_profile_id&conditions[0][value]=99&conditions[0][operator]=contains](https://openpaymentsdata.cms.gov/api/1/datastore/query/50fae62c-ced9-5e10-ad26-1cbc3381ac6b?keys=true&limit=5&offset=0&conditions%5B0%5D%5Bproperty%5D=covered_recipient_profile_id&conditions%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=99&conditions%5B0%5D%5Boperator%5D=contains)

My goal is to include multiple profile IDs into one request. As of now, I'm only able to view one covered recipient at a time. I used an in operator but I don't know how to format the URL for multiple IDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the correct format for IN operators in the request URL:

[https://openpaymentsdata.cms.gov/api/1/datastore/query/50fae62c-ced9-5e10-ad26-1cbc3381ac6b?keys=true&limit=100&offset=0&conditions[0][property]=covered_recipient_profile_id&conditions[0][operator]=in&conditions[0][value][1]=[ID1]&conditions[0][value][2]=[ID2]](https://openpaymentsdata.cms.gov/api/1/datastore/query/50fae62c-ced9-5e10-ad26-1cbc3381ac6b?keys=true&limit=100&offset=0&conditions%5B0%5D%5Bproperty%5D=covered_recipient_profile_id&conditions%5B0%5D%5Boperator%5D=in&conditions%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D%5B1%5D=%5BID1%5D&conditions%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D%5B2%5D=%5BID2%5D)